# Send error message and re-direct in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, redirect

Learning Express.js. I have the following simple HTML form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder = "First Number" value=""> <br>
      <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder = "Second Number" value=""> <br>
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The user is supposed to input two numbers, and their sum is returned to them. The simple Express server is here. `body-parser` is included in `node_modules` and `use`d by the Express `app` in order to manipulate the `req` object and extract the form data.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server spun on port 3000.")
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Serving a GET request at root route.");
  res.sendFile(absoluteDirPath() + "index.html");
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Serving a POST request at root route.");
  let num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
  let num2 = Number(req.body.num2);
  if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
     res.send("<p>Need numerical values.</p>"); 
   } else {
    res.send("<h3>Result: " + (num1 + num2) + "</h3>");
  }
  // How can I re-direct the user here? 
});

function absoluteDirPath() {
  const path = require('path');
  return __dirname + path.sep;
}
```

I am interested in redirecting the user to `index.html` in the `POST` middleware so that they can use the calculator again without refreshing the URL, whether they used it successfully or not. Since this is in the backend, I don't have access to the `window` object and I can't play around with it directly. Not sure how this could be done. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to decide. Do you want to continue to use the server for all actions or do you want to use AJAX to make calls to an API to handle your post/responses. Otherwise what you're doing kinda of invalidates the Post/Redirect/Get design pattern that lets the page shown after a form submission be reloaded, shared, or bookmarked without ill effects, such as submitting the form another time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect in express:

```js
res.redirect('/');
```

This doesn't exactly similate `window.location`, but it does redirect.

However, I don't see why you should redirect, because you are sending the client a message, and before they get to see it you already redirected them.

A better way to approach your problem would be to use AJAX (submitting a form without reloading the page); check out this jQuery example (client-side obviously):

```js
function submitFormWithoutReloading() {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/",
      data: {
         num1: $('#idOfYourFirstInput').val(),
         num2: $('#idOfYourSecondInput').val()
      },
      success: function(res) {
         alert(res); // This is what the server returns
      }
   });
}
```

Also, you can just use the provided variable `__dirname` for the absolute path.

Comment: I did not give the downvote, just to be clear. Validation *does* sound like something that the client ought to do. Thank you for the information! So, should this function be inside `<script>` tags after my HTML `<form>`? Do I just need to write it as a function in a linked `.js` file? Where would you write this function to ensure it gets called when the user clicks on the button? Event handler for the button?

Comment: So if you're using AJAX, you don't need to put the info inside a form, unless you give the form and ID, you could use `data: $('#idOfMyForm').serialize()` and it will give the same result. Regarding the script, you can put it either in a script tag or in another `.js` file. Just create a button (a regular one) with an event listener that calls the AJAX function (`submitFormWithoutReloading()`).

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'm accepting this answer, but the truth is that it caused me to get into an even bigger rabbit hole which was best explained with another SO post, which I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452097/combining-client-side-jquery-and-server-side-express). Any help you could provide would be appreciated; I seem to not be able to render client - side JavaScript / jQuery when I send an HTML file to my client using `res.sendFile()`. This makes my client - side validation impossible.

Comment: The solution is simple. You have to tell express which directory to be "public" (can be viewed by the client). Require path, then simply add this under `const app = express()`: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/path/to/your/folder/you/want/clients/to/be/able/to/see/the/content`)));`